# Angular2 cannot display the data from http when using route.params

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I am learning Angular2 to get data from $http GET request. Right now, the data doesn't show up. I think it's because my service passes the data after my component rendered. I did some search, but still didn't get it. I added two `console.log(data)` in my code and here is the screenshot of my console.[image]

Here is my `ngOnInit()` in **arr-detail.component.ts**:

```
import { TbArr } from './../../shared/models/tb_arr';
private data: TbArr;
ngOnInit() {
//method 1
  this.route.params
  .switchMap((params: Params) => this._dbService.get('MyAPI.php', 'id=' + params['id']))
  .subscribe((d:TbArr) => this.data = d)
  console.log(this.data);

/**method 2
* this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
*  this._dbService.get('MyAPI.php', 'id=' + this.id)
*       .subscribe(d => {
*         this.data = d;
*       });
**/
/**method 3
* this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
*   if (params['id']) { //got the id from url
*     this._dbService.get('MyAPI.php', 'id=' + params['id'])
*       .subscribe(d => {
*         this.data = d;
*       });
*   }
* });
**/
}
```

Here is my GET function in **db.service.ts**:

```
get(api: string, options: any) {
    return this.dbRequest('get', api, options);
}
dbRequest(method: string, api: string, options: string) {

    let observable: any;
    const backendUrl_json = 'http://XXX.XX.XX.XX/api/json/';
    observable = this.http[method](backendUrl_json + api, {search: options});
    observable = observable.map(res => res.json());
    console.log(method, backendUrl_update + api, options);
    observable.subscribe(
                d => { console.log(d); },
                e => { console.log(e); }
            );
    return observable;
}
```

Here is my component html file:

```
<table *ngIf="data">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ID:</td>
      <td>{{data?.id | async}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Date:</td>
      <td>{{data?.date | async}}</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Here is my **tb_arr** which has TbArr interface:

```
export interface TbArr {
   id:number;
   date:any;
}
```

UPDATE MY QUESTION:
  The table is showed up on web page, but no data showed.
  When I opened the "Object" in the console, I got this:
[image]

Does anyone have any idea about this? Thank you very much. If you need more information, please leave me a comment.

Comment: could you add how your json looks like... or more precise how the data looks like when you console.log it?

Comment: @AJT_82 I added the console screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see from your console.log that you are dealing with an object that is in an array. If you are always just receiving one object inside the array, extract it from the array.... Either you extract the object from the array when you subscribe, or you need to access it in your template appropriately, meaning:

```ts
{{data[0].id}}
```

Here I choose to extract the object in the subscription:

```ts
 this.route.params
  .switchMap((params: Params) => this._dbService.get('MyAPI.php', 'id=' + params['id']))
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data[0]; // extract the object
    console.log(this.data);
  })
```

Now you can access the properties of the object in your template:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ID:</td>
      <td>{{data?.id}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Date:</td>
      <td>{{data?.date}}</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Thank you. Thank you very much. It works like charming. I just noticed this is a really stupid question. Thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: You are very welcome... and as they say, there is no stupid questions, only stupid answers ;) Hey, we all make the silliest mistakes sometimes, at least I've had my share of facepalm moments :D But glad we got it sorted out. Have a great weekend and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

your `console.log()` is outside of the `subscribe()`... the call beign asynchronous, `this.data` is not populated yet.

this should work :

```js
 this.route.params
  .switchMap((params: Params) => this._dbService.get('MyAPI.php', 'id=' + params['id']))
  .subscribe((d:TbArr) => {
    this.data = d[0];
    console.log(this.data);
  })
```

Putting an `async` pipe on data does not makes sense, as `data` is not an observable :

```html
<td>{{data?.date | async}}</td> <!-- wrong ! -->
<td>{{data?.date}}</td> <!-- right ! -->
```

Comment: I modified my code based on your suggestion. But only the console shows    the data, my web page still doesn't show any data. Do you have any idea why it doesn't show up?